# Getting a specific column value from a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

## The problem

I've got three tables, `shops`, `products`, and `product_shop`as the pivot table. The `Shop` and `Product` are related using a `belongsToMany` (Many to Many). When inserting a new `Product` into the database, in my form I can specify a price for each `Shop`. When submitting the form, the `product_id` and `shop_id's` are being inserted into the Pivot table with their related prices.

My question is, how do I retrieve only the price of a product from the pivot table, when specifying a `shop_id`? Ultimately, my goal is described below, and there might be a better solution for this.

## Explanation

Furthermore, why I need this is the following. I have a `categories` table as well. And in my `index view` I want to do something like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category) // All categories
    {{ $category->name }} // Display the name of the category

    @foreach($category->products as $product) // Loop through all related products for each category
        {{ $product->name }}
        {{ $product->price }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Now the trick is that the price is coming from the pivot table. I want to display the above based on the `shop_id`. Ideally, I just want to create a query where I select everything that I need, and then use that collection in my foreach, so I do not have to use specific methods in my views. So basically what I need is something along the lines of this:

```
select
    categories->with('products') // Select all categories while eager loading the products
    price // Collected from the pivot table where the shop_id is equal to the given shop_id
```

## Database Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id`,
  `user_id`,
  `name`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)

CREATE TABLE `shops` (
`id`,
  `user_id`,
  `name`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)

CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id`,
  `user_id`,
  `category_id`,
  `name`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)

CREATE TABLE `product_shop` (
`id`,
  `product_id`,
  `shop_id`,
  `price`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`
)
```

## Ideal end result (with the price collected from the pivot table included):

[image: with the price entered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself in the end, since all the answers above were not 100% what I was looking for, unfortunately.

```
public function price($shop_id)
{
    return $this->shops()->where('shop_id', $shop_id)->first()->pivot->price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your product.php (Model) file define this relation

```
public function priceCol($shopId)
{
  return $this->belongsTo(ProductShop::class,'product_id')->where('shop_id',$shopId);
}
```

For retrieving the price of a specific product

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$price = $product->priceCol($shopId)->price;
```

Comment: Probably this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Using eloquent:

```
$shop=Shop::where('id',$id)->first();
$shop->pivot->price;
```

Also, make sure you use `->withPivot` in relation:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('price');;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Product` model define this

```
public function shops () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class)->wirhPivot('price'); 
}
```

Then you can

```
Product::with('shops')->get();
```

To eager load and the resulting collection will have the price